# How to set List Mode(backend configuration) programmatically for category page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, programmatically, category-listing, system-configuration

> Actually i want to set list/grid mode(List Mode) configuration values
>   for category page programmatically not from magento admin backend.if
>   anyone have any idea please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" 
            type="Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

**ListProduct.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Product;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct{
        public function getMode()
        {

        }
    }
```

**Check This File :-**

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

**Line No. 28 :-**

```
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
```

Comment: your approach is correct only, but  i want to set $block->getMode() value i.e. grid/list programmatically.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml this file put in your theme

Comment: /app/design/frontend/thme/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/ paste file in this location

Comment: i have idea related but i don't want to change from list.phtml,i am trying to set configuration values programmatically

Comment: which file you want to get value ?

Comment: i want to set $block->getMode() this value programmatically

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct under this file getMode() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91919/discussion-between-hitesh-balpande-and-ronak-rathod).

Comment: you can override this file and get the value

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using preference if possible as getMode() is a public function you can use a plugin instead.